# socket.io порт https

Tags: node.js, сокет, express, socket.io

есть сайт на node.js + express + socket.io. Сайт работает на 4000 порту, а сокет на 4001. Сайт работает на https. Как сокет переадресовывать на https?
Спасибо

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server)

server.listen(4001);

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    // console.log('User connected:' + socket.id);

    });
});
```